# Why the number of stm32f103c8t6's timers in reference manual differ from datasheet

Tags: stm32f1

I'm working with stm32f103c8t6, in the block diagram there are only 4 timers but in the reference manual there are 14 timers (2 advanced control, 10 general purpose, 2 basic), why is that ?

I have googled it but couldn't find any answer

Comment: Can you list the 14 timers?  There are 7 as far as I know...

Comment: i can briefly listed as below:
Advanced-control timers(TIM1 and TIM8)
General-purpose timers(TIM2 to TIM5)
General-purpose timers(TIM9 to TIM14)
Basic timer(TIM 6 and TIM7)